# How can I find the neighbours of a router in the network?

Tags: python, router, topology

My final design topic is about choosing the best path. I intend to use a server which can get the best route and return the result(**Centralized processing**, the result will contain all node information on the path).

So I need to build a structure diagram of **network topology**, I think that I can **use the neighbor table** to get my result, but don't know how to get the **neighbor table** of a router.

There may be other better solutions to get the topology.If can't do it, saving the routing table in advance  can be a good idea.

Really thanks for answering.

Comment: Ordinarily, you would build such a diagram manually, by talking to the people who made the connections.  Are you hoping to build this automatically?

Comment: yeah，my final design topic is about choosing the best path. I intend to use a server which can get the best route and return a  result of SRv6 protocol, so I want get the topology.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your network is 100% Cisco, you can log in to the routers to fetch this info.  If not, I'm not convinced there is a way.  The routers support BGP to communicate peer-to-peer, but I'm not aware of a "dump my state" ability.

Comment: OK，thanks for your advice. I'm not a English native-speaker, so my reply may be a little late and reads a little strange. Really thank you.